How to extrude a profile along multiple curves keeping tilt equal between instances and sane normals?
Context
I need to create something like this:
But geometry should be fine, tips should be normal to the shape tangents and bases shoud not be rotated they should form hex pattern like in the example.
I had two options:

Mesh modeling, like in example. This way does not suit me: it has not ideal geometry because lattice deforms every vertice so sections become distorted, it could be seen on tips, their normals are rather point up, should point tangent to the shape.
Curve extrusion with geo nodes, should be ideal but i couldnt extrude profile properly.

What i did
I extruded a vertex up 4 times, set vertex weights to them(weights will control lattice deform). Made geo nodes that instanciate those 4 vertexes in hex pattern, deformed them with lattice, tried to make geo nodes that would extrude that. I got nice smooth cureves from that instances of deformed pattern of triple edges, result:
Next i tried many things to get hex extruded, like tune curve points normals, set tilt to opposite of that of each instance to compensate the rotation of the curves but each time something of the needs were not satisfied, when i fixed one problem - another emerged again. Next i attach all the problems i encountered trying to extrude properly.
Question
How to extrude those curves keeping all requirements? Again, requirements are: not broken hex pattern, straight tips, fine geometry. Fine geometry might not be ideal, maybe its not possible but it should be as straight as possible
Side question
How curve to mesh node decides the orientation of extruded meshes? I checked the normals, all of them was approx along X+ but after curve to mesh node geometry was like normals actually were not along X+:↑ Here ↑ set curves normals should be minimum twist, imagine it is(arrows stays same direction)


Why do you use "Edge Paths to Curves" instead of just "Mesh to Curve"? Does the below work for you? I simply captured the normal and restored it after setting radii:




Thank you! I didnt use Mesh to Curve because the name says that it should output a curve but i needed multiple curves that is what confused me. Also i would like to ask you why you captured curves normals after Set Spline Type and reapplied after Set Curve Radius? Does Set Curve Radius somehow mess the normals so we need to reverse that?

@jopandla exactly, it changes the calculation of minimum twist normals
